# Cannot get sertificate from Certbot --apache

Tags: linux, unix, system-administration

When I try the command sudo cerbot --apache -d page1.com it returns this error:
Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80 which is currently needed for Certbot to prove to the CA that you control your domain. Please add a virtual host for port 80.

This is my configuration file, it seems ok for me:
000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName page1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/page1

<Directory /var/www/page1>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example2
<Directory /var/www/example2>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also directories, have index.html
I tried everything but nothing works.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Alright this is super vague but we can get you there.

Note: I did notice you have `ServerName`, also set your `ServerAlias` with the `www` suffix. So it would become `www.page1.com`

Firstly too, check your output `sudo apache2ctl configtest` that may show you where it is running into errors.

1. What operating system are you running? Is this WSL or native Linux?
2. Cloud, or a "server" like system on your LAN?
3. In your `routers` firewall, have you port forwarded 80 & 443 to the device on your LAN (your server)?
4. Are you running your server on the host OS, container, or VM?
5. Find out what ports you are listening on:

`sudo ss -ltnp`

- `ss` - "another utility to investigate sockets" standard utility in linux

  - flags:

    -l Display only listening sockets

    -t Protocol TCP

    -n Do not try to resolve service names. Show exact bandwidth values, instead of human-readable.

    -p processes using the socket

Comment: 1. I am on Linux Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: 2. Not cloud, I have task to create 2 virtual hosts on port 80 and one on port 8080, after that to certificate them with certbot. Finally I have to change the port from 8080 to 443

Comment: That is the output from 'sudo apache2ctl configtest' : AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.228.147. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Comment: Now when I try to 'sudo certbot --apache' this is the error :Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: apache). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: www.page1.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 52.20.84.62: Invalid response from http://www.page1.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/kwWTIXNNKYDsOvxq_ZSRjeRRg4mT5ikGfM-OeZhHqqI: 404

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the temporary Apache configuration changes made by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains point to this Apache server and that it is accessible from the internet.